# Unable to deploy my React App to GitHub properly

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, create-react-app

not able to deploy my react app properly on GitHub pages. I created it using create-react-app.

I have followed each step of the instructions given [by facebook](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages) properly to deploy react apps on GitHub pages.

In the end, I ran "yarn run deploy" and the deployment seemed to work fine without any errors and I saw this success message saying that deployment was completed successfully in 65.73 sec:
[image]

But, when I check my app at https://aksheyjawa.github.io/YSearch/ it doesn't show my app. It shows a documentation created by react. I was expecting to see my app.

I have done the steps needed to deploy:

- Added 'homepage' to package.json
- Installed gh-pages
- Added deploy to scripts in package.json
- Deployed using 'npm run deploy'

You can check the code here: https://github.com/aksheyjawa/YSearch

Possible issue:

According to step 4 [in docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages), I need to select gh-pages branch in GitHub settings. But I can't see that branch in the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Have you pushed the gh-pages branch? E.g. `git push -u origin gh-pages:gh-pages`.

Comment: @AKX It seems there is no gh-pages branch locally also. I was expecting it to be generated automatically.
I did 'git branch' and was shown only 'master' branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is that `gh-pages` branch is not getting created. This should be created automatically.

In your [`package.json`](https://github.com/aksheyjawa/YSearch/blob/master/package.json), I don't see the following

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

Even after you add these, if `yarn predeploy` and `yarn deploy` doesn't work, try running the following.

```
./node_modules/gh-pages/bin/gh-pages -d build
```

This command uses binary from `node_modules` directory to run the scripts same as `"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"`

This should ideally create `gh-pages` branch. If it does, you're all set. You just have to push this branch and set it from GitHub interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy only the content inside of your build folder to display something. Github pages are only to static HTML!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I provided a link to my repository, not to an actual page and that was the mistake. I wrote `https://github.com/user-name/project-name` instead of `https://user-name.github.io/project-name/`. May be this will help.